# Spring resource not found - 3.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, xsd

We have a project which is using Spring with 3.0 xsd running on tomcat 7. I tried to change the xsd to Spring 3.2 as we have been using spring jars for spring 3.2.4 and 'exclude-mapping' cannot be used with spring 3.0 xsd.

After this change, application stops working, though it does not throw any errors while starting/stopping the server or adding and removing the application.

After the change any request to the application fails with error 404.

Here are the Jars we are using:

```
beandoc-0.7.0.jar
 commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
 commons-io-1.3.2.jar
 commons-logging-1.2-javadoc.jar
 commons-logging-1.2.jar
 jstl.jar
 log4j-1.2.14.jar
 ojdbc6.jar
 slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
 slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
 spring-beandoc-0.7.1.jar
 spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
 spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
 spring-context-support-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
 spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
 spring-dao-2.0.8.jar
 spring-expression-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
 spring-jdbc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
 spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
 spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
 spring-webmvc-portlet-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
 standard.jar
```

When we try to clean the server, it results in the below exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting Context with name [/COETOOLSACCL]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/COETOOLSACCL]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4119)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1341)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1520)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletRequestHandledEvent
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:387)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5503)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletRequestHandledEvent
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1891)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1734)
    ... 22 more
```

This exception prevails regardless of the xsd versions and with 3.0 application runs normal despite we get this error while cleaning the server.

Please help.

Comment: ...Spring 3.4? In any case, it's a standard `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: Chryls, of what I gather from googling is, this error usually means missing jars or wrong version of jars. In this case this exception somehow isn't affecting the application in any noticeable way if I use xsd 3.0